# При попытке воспроизвести аудио файл с CD карты, программа выдает ошибку

Tags: java, android

Я хочу запустить аудио файл с СD карты своего телефона, но когда я пытаюсь это сделать программа выдает ошибку IllegalStateException в строке mediaPlayer.prepare(). Я не совсем понимаю из-за чего это происходит. Поиск в гугле особым успехом не увенчался. Если можно то опишите почему это происходит и как с этим бороться.

Вот мой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

    private final File DATA_SD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String name = DATA_SD + "music.mp3";

    private Button play_button;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play_button = findViewById(R.id.play_button);

        play_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.play_button:

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .build());

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(name);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать `prepareAsync`.

Comment: Вероятно `setDataSource` вызывает ошибку - поищите в логах `IOException`, указывающий на эту строку